# Waiting for both Spinners to have an item selected

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have two Spinners in my main view. I have a list of items in those Spinners and I do use `adapter.getItem(position)` because I need to get the value (let's say `value1` and `value2`) I want to wait for the user to select an item in BOTH of the Spinners, then when that occurs at any give time, I want to execute some code. What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this? Should I check in the `onItemSelected` if `value1` or `value2` is null? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking nulls sounds good to me.

```
//inside onItemSelected()
if (spinner1value != null && spinner2value != null) {
   DoYourStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2In pseudo code I will do something like this:

```
spinner1Selected = false;
spinner2Selected = false;

Spinner1ItemSelected {
   spinner1Selected = true;
   if(spinner1Selected == true && spinner2Selected == true) doMyStuff();
}

Spinner2ItemSelected {
    spinner1Selected = true;
    if(spinner1Selected == true && spinner2Selected == true) doMyStuff();
}

doMyStuff(){
    doing my stuff...

    spinner1Selected = false;
    spinner2Selected = false;
}
```